# crontab not working (php exec)

Tags: php, cron

---- Source

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$domain = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'domain', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$terms = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'terms', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

require_once('/home/myaccount/www/scrap/goutte-v2.0.4.phar');
include_once('/home/myaccount/www/scrap/common.php');

$command = "ps -ef|grep data_scrap.php";
$commandResult = shell_exec($command);
$commandResultArray = explode("\n", $commandResult);

if(sizeof($commandResultArray) == 6) {
    echo "[".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] working...".PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($commandResultArray);
    exit;
} else {
    echo "[".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] not working...".PHP_EOL;
}
.
.  php scrpt
.
```

---- Crontab Schedule

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /cron_script/data_scrap.php >> /cron_script/data_scrap_log.txt
```

---- Crontab Log (syslog)

```
Jan  7 12:10:01 dev CRON[2051]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/php /cron_script/data_scrap.php >> /cron_script/data_scrap_log.txt) 
Jan  7 12:10:01 dev postfix/pickup[643]: 6D6B113A1191: uid=0 from=<root> 
Jan  7 12:10:01 dev postfix/cleanup[2018]: 6D6B113A1191: message-id=<20160107031001.6D6B113A1191@mydomain> 
Jan  7 12:10:01 dev postfix/qmgr[14721]: 6D6B113A1191: from=<root@mail.mydomain>, size=623, nrcpt=1 (queue active) 
Jan  7 12:10:01 dev postfix/local[2021]: 6D6B113A1191: to=<root@mail.mydomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.31, delays=0.28/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir) 
Jan  7 12:10:01 dev postfix/qmgr[14721]: 6D6B113A1191: removed
```

---- cat /cron_script/data_scrap_log.txt

```
null
```

---- file permission

```
chown myaccount:myaccount data_scrap.php
chmod 777 data_scrap.php
chmod +x data_scrap.php
```

why do not working crontab?

php /cron_script/data_scrap.php -> It will run.

please your help.

Comment: You can't provide `$_POST` from the command line. `$domain` and `$terms` will always be empty.

Comment: Is the user cron is running under allowed to write to `/cron_script/data_scrap_log.txt`?

Comment: redirect all output into the log, stderr and stdout, `*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /cron_script/data_scrap.php >> /cron_script/data_scrap_log.txt 2>&1` and check for errors, the script might be running but there could be errors

Comment: /cron_script permission 775
data_scrap_log.txt permission 777

Comment: Your crontab seems to be sending error messages per email to your root-user. Change to the root user and read your emails.

Comment: @AlexAndrei log text "/bin/sh: 1: root: not found"

Comment: please post the output of `which php` and is the the full path of `data_scrap.php` **exactly** `/cron_script/data_scrap.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `crontab` entry as follows

```
*/1 * * * * /cron_script/data_scrap.php >> /cron_script/data_scrap_log.txt 2>&1
```

Removing `root` and the path to the `php` binary, since the `php` file has the `shebang`